# Enforce two structs to have same size at compile time?

Tags: c, embedded

I have defined two data structures that must remain the same size as each other for the application to function properly.  The struct's are used to communicate between a PC and a DSP.  The DSP code is in 'C', the PC side in C++.

for example:

```
struct inbound_data{
    int header[5];
    float val1;
    float val2;
    int trailer[3];
};

struct outbound_data{
    int header[5];
    int reply1;
    int reply2;
    float dat1;
    float dat2;
    int filler[1];
}
```

later I will do something like:

```
int tx_block[sizeof(outbound_data)];
int rx_block[sizeof(inbound_data)];
```

These arrays will be passed to the communication peripherals to transmit and receive between the devices.

Because of how the hardware works, it is essential that the size of the two structs match, so that the buffers are of equal size.  This is easy enough to assure with proper care, but occasionally through the design cycle, the data structures get modified.  If one is not extremely careful, and aware of the requirement that the structures stay the same size (and be reflected in the PC side code as well), chaos ensues.

I would like to find a compile time way to have the code not build if one of the structures gets modified so that it does not match the size of the other structure.

Is this possible somehow in 'standard' C to check the sizes at compile time and fail if they are different? (I think my compiler is at least C99, maybe not 11).

Comment: You can use `sizeof()` to get the size of something. Perhaps use it with a conditional macro that causes a compile time error if the size isn't what it should be.

Comment: @Blaze Nit: `sizeof` is not a function. :)

Comment: @unwind haha yep... this is something that occasionally slips my mind and surprises me for a second here and then when I type it and the syntax highlighting is that of a keyword.

Comment: *later I will do something like: `int tx_block[sizeof(outbound_data)];`*  I hope not.  That will create an `int` array that has a number of `int` elements that is the same as the number of bytes in the `outbout_data` structure.  The last element of the array will be way past where the last element of the structure would be if you `memcpy()`'d it into the array on any system where `sizeof( int )` is greater than one.

Comment: Andrew, you are correct.  In the DSP, sizeof returns the number of 32 bit words, which is also the size of an int on that platform.  In the PC it is different and we take that into account on that side.

Comment: Why not just put them in a union - the union will automatically be as large as the larger struct (plus padding) - seems much simpler than messing about

Comment: But OTOH that will allow you to try send structs between binaries which are possibly  different endian/packing/int-size, so on second thoughts don’t bother with any of these approaches - you need to encode/decode the data to platform-neutral binary stream to xfer between platforms

Comment: Union is what you are looking for, or you can specify the memory layout using compiler directives, such as pack() and pack(pop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you must use C99, then I too [like Swordfish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608691/817643) would suggest a macro. The way to make one which can appear anywhere, and would not introduce any objects for the optimizer to remove, is to put the invalid array in a `typedef`. So a more general purpose static assertion would look this:

```
#define CONCAT_(A,B) A##B
#define CONCAT(A,B) CONCAT_(A,B)
#define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(p, msg) typedef char CONCAT(dummy__,__LINE__) [(p) ? 1 : -1]
```

It's designed to mimic `_Static_assert`. The message is passed in with the hopes of a compiler diagnostic showing it. An example for its usage is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d42d079ff012a52e).

Which produces:

```
main.cpp:4:54: error: size of array 'dummy__13' is negative
 #define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(p, msg) typedef char CONCAT(dummy__,__LINE__) [(p) ? 1 : -1]
                                                      ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:2:22: note: in definition of macro 'CONCAT_'
 #define CONCAT_(A,B) A##B
                      ^
main.cpp:4:47: note: in expansion of macro 'CONCAT'
 #define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(p, msg) typedef char CONCAT(dummy__,__LINE__) [(p) ? 1 : -1]
                                               ^~~~~~
main.cpp:13:1: note: in expansion of macro 'MY_STATIC_ASSERT'
 MY_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(struct foo) == sizeof(struct baz), "Do not match!");
```

And all the way down there you can see the static assertion with the message.

---

As an afterthought, you can change `dummy__` to `please_check_line_` will will produce the more descriptive `please_check_line_13` above.

Comment: This works perfectly.  All of the answers were helpful, and I will probably use P__J's suggestion, because it actually accomplishes more for me than what I asked.  Since this answer most directly answers what I asked, I am marking it as the solution.  I will certainly use this in my code as well.  Thanks.

Comment: This has the added benefit that when editing in Visual Studio, it picks this up even before compiling.  I get red ink on the MY_STATIC_ASSERT when the predicate is false.  Very nice.  (I edit in VS and compile with the AD toolchain)

Comment: Why is there both `CONCAT_` and `CONCAT`, since `CONCAT` directly calls to `CONCAT_`?

Comment: @Caramiriel - The preprcoessor won't exapnd `__LINE__` in `CONCAT(dummy__,__LINE__)`. If we were to concat right away we'd get `dummy____LINE__`. An extra pass is required to make sure everuthing is expanded prior to token pasting.

Answer (score 6):

The C11 Standard added a new keyword `_Static_assert`. You can use it to test a predicate at compile-time, and produce an error if it is `false`:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(outbound_data) == sizeof(inbound_data), "sizes must match");
```

Comment: It does not appear that my environment is C11 compliant.  I don't find any reference to _Static_assert, and attempting to use it does not build.  Otherwise that is exactly what I want.

Comment: @ttemple Which compiler are you using?  For gcc, you can set c11 mode with the flag `--std=c11` or `--std=gnu11`.

Comment: Analog Devices 'Visual DSP++' V5.2.1 - it is a specialized compiler for their DSP's.

Answer (score 6):

> Enforce two structs have same size at compile time?

There is no standard way to enforce this in C. There are only ways to *protect it from happening*, such as `static_assert` - which prevents buggy code from compiling but doesn't solve the actual problem.

In your case there are several problems:

- Your struct is using the naive default types of C. These aren't portable and can have any size. This can easily be fixed by swapping `int` for `int32_t` etc.
- Endianess might make the code non-portable regardless of integer type. That's a separate issue that I won't address here, but it needs to be considered, especially for exotic DSPs.
- Any struct can contain padding bytes anywhere, to sate system-specific alignment requirements. The root of the problem being that alignment works differently on different systems. This is the hard one to solve.

The dirty fix to avoid padding is to use `static_assert` together with some non-standard solution to ensure that the struct has the expected size. Such as `#pragma pack(1)` or gcc `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` etc. These are not standard nor are they portable. Furthermore, skipping padding can be problematic on many systems and you can get issues with misaligned access - padding is there for a reason. So this can potentially create more problems than it solves.

So unfortunately we end up with the realisation that `struct` is unsuitable for portable code. Particularly for things like data protocol specifications.

If you need truly portable, rugged code, it leaves you with only one option, namely to use a raw data array of `uint8_t`. In case you need to translate this array into structs, you will have to write serialization/de-serialization code. Which will cost run-time overhead. But there's no other way around it, if you want truly portable structs.

Comment: Your comments are well taken.  Portability is not an issue here, but protecting me from myself is.  The PC side is fixed, as well as the DSP side.  We have already worked through the endian, padding, etc.  (which in our case amounts to sticking with certain data types that we have proven to work and align properly between the two sides.)  In the case of the DSP we are using, sizeof returns 32 bit words, and the PC returns bytes, so we have to account for that as well.  At least doing the static assert, and/or automating the padding size gives some level of protection.

Answer (score 3):

For C99 you could use something like

```
#define C_ASSERT(x, y) { int dummy[(x) == (y) ? 1 : -1]; (void*)dummy; }

struct foo {
    int f;
};

struct bar {
    int b1;
    //int b2;
};

int main()
{
    C_ASSERT(sizeof(struct foo), sizeof(struct bar));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fail at compile time for me.  I don't completely understand how it is supposed to fail.  Can you explain it?

Comment: When the values of `x` doesn't compare equal to `y` an array of negative size is declared, which is illegal. The `(void*)dummy;` should suppress warning about an unused variable `dummy`.

Comment: @ttemple You should use StoryTellers version, though, since it will give more meaningful error messages.

Answer (score 1):

you can add padding to equalize the size

```
struct inbound_data;
struct outbound_data;

struct _inbound_data{
    int header[5];
    float val1;
    float val2;
    int trailer[3];
};

struct _outbound_data{
    int header[5];
    int reply1;
    int reply2;
    float dat1;
    float dat2;
    int filler[1];
};

struct inbound_data{
    int header[5];
    float val1;
    float val2;
    int trailer[3];
    char padding[sizeof(struct _inbound_data) < sizeof(struct _outbound_data) ? sizeof(struct _outbound_data) - sizeof(struct _inbound_data) : 0];
};

struct outbound_data{
    int header[5];
    int reply1;
    int reply2;
    float dat1;
    float dat2;
    int filler[1];
    char padding[sizeof(struct _outbound_data) < sizeof(struct _inbound_data) ? sizeof(struct _inbound_data) - sizeof(struct _outbound_data) : 0];
};
```

I it can be of course written shorter way without the struct members duplication - but I did it intentionally to show the idea.

```
struct inbound_data1 __attribute__((packed){
    struct _inbound_data id;
    char padding[sizeof(struct _inbound_data) < sizeof(struct _outbound_data) ? sizeof(struct _outbound_data) - sizeof(struct _inbound_data) : 0];
};

struct outbound_data1 __attribute__((packed){
    struct _outbound_data od;
    char padding[sizeof(struct _outbound_data) < sizeof(struct _inbound_data) ? sizeof(struct _inbound_data) - sizeof(struct _outbound_data) : 0];
};
```

Comment: I will end up using some variation of this.  It is not what I asked for, but it is what I want.  I can use something like this on the C and C++ side, possibly sharing the same header file to keep things automatically aligned in both programs.  Thanks.

Comment: @ttemple For me the title of the topic is about enforcing the same size not about preventing compilation if they are different.

Comment: You may be right, but my intention was compiler enforce.  quote... "I would like to find a compile time way to have the code not build " from my post.  Maybe the title was misleading, sorry.